# Generate node edit link

Tags: 8, nodes

I'm attempting to dynamically generate a node edit link. I understand that I can manually create it by using

$editpath = '/node/'.$nid.'/edit';

but I have multiple sites that use subfolders like

> /site1_subfolder/node/123/edit

and

> /site2_subfolder/node/123/edit

I looked at the node class and I couldn't see any method that would generate this link for me. I did see that there's a NodeForm class but I didn't see any static methods I could take advantage of either.

Given a node or node id is there a way to generate an admin edit link to its edit form?

NOTE: If that's not possible I would be fine with using a function to get the subfolder names so I could do $editpath = '/'.$subfolder_name.'/node/'.$nid.'/edit';

But I'm not sure how to do that either.

UPDATE: I suppose I could do a $node->toUrl()->toString() to get the direct path and add edit at the end but this would only give me the alias, is there a way to not get the alias from this and get the direct link to the node instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Given a node or node id is there a way to generate an admin edit link to its edit form?

Absolutely, the `Url` class has a [`fromRoute`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromRoute/8.5.x) method:

```
$url = Url::fromRoute('entity.node.edit_form', ['node' => $nid]);
$link = Link::fromTextAndUrl('edit', $url);
$build = [
  ...
  'link' => $link->toRenderable(),
];
```

Answer (score 9):

> Given a node or node id is there a way to generate an admin edit link to its edit form?

If you have the `$node` itself, then you can you can use the [`toUrl()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3AtoUrl) method to get one of the defined links:

```
$url = $node->toUrl('edit-form');
$link = Link::fromTextAndUrl('Title', $url);
$build = [
  //...
  'link' => $link->toRenderable(),
];
```

The various link names for the entity are on the annotation for the [Node class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!src!Entity!Node.php/class/Node):

```
/**
 * Defines the node entity class.
 *
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "node",
 *   ...
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/node/{node}",
 *     "delete-form" = "/node/{node}/delete",
 *     "delete-multiple-form" = "/admin/content/node/delete",
 *     "edit-form" = "/node/{node}/edit",
 *     "version-history" = "/node/{node}/revisions",
 *     "revision" = "/node/{node}/revisions/{node_revision}/view",
 *     "create" = "/node",
 *   }
 * )
 */
```